# LDAP Query to check if User is a member of a particular security group

Tags: ldap

I am trying to adapt the following query to find out if a user is a member of a specific group (security group) but I do not get it to work and I fail to understand it completely.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=yourUserName)
  (memberof=CN=YourGroup,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com))
```

in my case, the user is XYZ and the `security group` is called [SecITGroup].
The user is however located under `OU=USERS OU=GO OU=AzureSync`.

I have tried the following:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=XYZ)
      (memberof=CN=SecITGroup,OU=AzureSync,OU=GO,OU=USR,DC=de,DC=domain,DC=int))
```

yes, I set the domain name to the actual domain and `No result is shown` is displayed.
What is the `return attribute` am I supposed to get back?

Comment: What I like to achieve with this is to query: if user is a member of the XYZgroup and then show a result  Yes or No / or anything that gives an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution or a workaround to this.
The LDAP Query is rather to say show me users in the specific group:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=Administrators,OU=Admin,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com))
```

The `attribute` is **sAMAccountname** which displays the user's name.